# VB Net - Need some structural guidance

Tags: vb.net, while-loop

I need some ideas on how I can accomplish what I'm attempting to do, here is the scenario.

I have 2 DateTimePickers (DateTimePicker1 and DateTimePicker2) to act as a date range. I need a function to :

```
1.) Download a file from my ftp with the initial date/time in yyyyMMdd.txt format
2.) Add 1 to the date and do the download again until DateTimePicker1 = DateTimePicker2
3.) If the file doesn't exist (its possible it may not), just move on to the next date.
```

I managed to create an infinite loop! It just won't repeat. I'm not familiar with Do While loops so any tips are weclomed!

I tried something like:

```
While DateTimePicker1 < DateTimePicker2
    Do My.Computer.Network.FileDownload("ftp://address/", "ftp://address/" & folder & "/" & DateTimePicker1 & ".txt")
    DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1)
    Loop
```

Comment: You'll have better success with your question if you post the code you are having trouble with, and being specific about which part of the code you need help with.  As it stands now, it's hard to give a proper answer.

Comment: Move the Do to before While (to be Do While) and all should be fine, Currently your Do loop has no condition to stop. I am surprised it even compiles though, I would have thought it would complain that there was no Wend for the While loop (You effectively have two loops in your code currently and the inner one has no exit clause)

Comment: The while statement would have generated an end while statement. Your do and loop statements are mostlikly wrpped inside of the while/endwhile statements. The code is looping forever without ever testing at the while statement.

For proof, Write the date to the console output window inside of the do loop.  Alternatively, Hit the pause button and hover over your variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to compare the `Value` properties of the `DateTimePicker`s and when you call `AddDays()` you have to assign the result back to the `Value` property like this:

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1)
```

The `Value` property is a `DateTime` object and `AddDays()` returns the `DateTime` object as a result.

So try this...

```
While DateTimePicker1.Value < DateTimePicker2.Value
    My.Computer.Network.FileDownload("ftp://address/", "ftp://address/" & folder & "/" & DateTimePicker1 & ".txt")
    DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.AddDays(1)
End While
```

Here's a [Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o2jSkU) with just DateTime objects.

Comment: thank you to everyone who replied! i got the code working thanks to your suggestions.